# I am wiring a 240V heater that will draw 30Amps max

Tags: electrical-panel

The heater will be hard-wired and hung from the ceiling.  Is 10g wire ok, and do I use a double 30A breaker or does the current split and do I use a double 15A?

Comment: What model is the heater? It would be better if you could post a link to the instructions so we don't miss details.

Comment: What do the instructions say?

Answer (score 6):

If the heater **DRAWS 30A**, you need 30/0.8==30*1.25==37.5A due to **derating**, so a 40A breaker and 8 gauge copper.

If the heater nameplate **specifies a breaker of 30A**, 30A and 10 gauge copper. And it will *draw* 24A or less.

A double breaker is a breaker for 240V loads (USA/Canada system) and a 240V 30A load needs a 240V 30A breaker, not a 240V 15A breaker. The full current flows from one line back to the other, so each breaker pole needs to be rated at the rated current.

Answer (score 1):

First consideration is the instructions and labelling. The UL/CSA/ETL Listing is only valid when installed and used as specified in the instructions, and the NEC specifies following them.

If it comes with a cord and plug then normally the largest size breaker allowed for the matching receptacle is acceptable.

Both poles of the breaker need to be rated for full amperage for 240v equipment.

Then NEC Article 424 says to size conductor and overcurrent protection at 125% of nameplate current, so for breakers recognized as normal sizes in NEC 240.6:

#10 and 25A breaker is needed for 3840 to 4800 watts (20 amps)
#10 and 30A breaker is needed for 4801 to 5760 (24A)
#8 (copper) and 35A is needed for 5751 to 6720 (28A)
#8 (copper) and 40A is needed for 6721 to 7680 (32A)

Answer (score 0):

10 gauge is correct and no the current doesn't "split" into a two 15 amp runs.  You need a 30 amp breaker which will take up two slots in your box.  There are plenty of websites that can walk you through this, but please cover those nuts on the main cables coming into your home as soon as you open the breaker box up. Use heavy cardboard and tape, just in case you lean into the box.  I have a box with recessed nuts, but I don't think that is the norm.

Comment: Thanks much for the answers people.  Appreciated.  I got it now.